# REST webservice with Android client vs RPC

Tags: android, rest, rpc

We are still trying to decide between implementing a REST webservice vs going with RPC. Googles eclipse plugin makes it very easy to create an RPC service which is what the main attraction is for the RPC way.
However, a REST service would seem to be easier to modify, IMHO,  and would also allow for a future iOS client to connect with little or no rework.
One concern I would have and maybe this is a problem with RPC also or indeed any Client-Server model is how do you modify your existing service and allow old clients to still work while allowing new clients to use the new functionality.
What I mean is can you point me towards any thing we should look out for when modifying a web service so as not to break existing clients or force them to upgrade.  Any links you have that would cover this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Few thoughts here.  First, as I've pointed out in similar questions it doesn't really make sense to compare REST and RPC.  REST is a set of constraints that can be imposed on an interface to achieve a particular set of goals, and RPC interfaces can actually be RESTful.  See [this](http://www.etherealbits.com/2012/12/debunking-the-myths-of-rpc-rest/) blog post for more information.

In response to the second part of your question, you are correct that in a custom RPC interface the client has to know about what methods it's calling which means that API breaking changes to the procedures that are exposed make rolling out a new version of the service more challenging (whereas in a RESTful interface legal actions are typically all controlled by the server).  The blog post that I linked talks about this in some detail as well.

One approach to roll out multiple versions of a service side by side is to roll service versions in production multi-tenant, and dispatching requests to the correct service version based on arbitrary client metadata.  For example if your service exposes an RPC web API via a Servlet, you can:

1. Bootstrap multiple versions of the RPC service side by side in Tomcat with [Class Loader](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) separation.
2. Have your client pass in some contextual information (for example on the querystring) about the version of the RPC service that it's expecting.
3. Create a [Servlet Mapping](http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/) that routes to the correct version of your service based on the parameter.

In most client/server scenarios multiple versions of the client will exist at any time in the wild, so without the server controlling legal actions the best solution is to run multiple versions in parallel on the server while old version of the client are deprecated.